# Rails change default timezone

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to change default timezone in Rails 3.2.8 app to GMT+04:00, but I don't know how to do it. The following solutions do not work for me:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
config.time_zone = "(GMT+04:00) Moscow"
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Moscow'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Also I've tried in rails console the following:

```
 ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

which returned a list of values, including `"Moscow"`.
`Time.zone` returned `(GMT+00:00) UTC` which is not correct, it should be `(GMT+04:00) UTC`. Then I changed `Time.zone = "Moscow"` and `Time.now` returned the correct value (... +0400).

So to fix it I simply used `Time.now + 4.hour`, but I also need datetime_select to display my local time. `Time.now + 4.hour` is not a correct solution.

How one can set default time zone to their local value?

Comment: Have you checked out a recently revise RailsCast on this topic?  http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of a sudden I've localized the problem.
I run Win7 and my WEBrick server is showing the correct time, but the project itself shows a wrong one. In the same time, my production server is working correctly, so, obviously, the problem is with the OS.
**UPD**: The problem is fixed. I should have restarted the WEBrick server after changing the application.rb file.

Comment: If you have updates to questions, please use the edit link, and change the original question, rather than adding an answer.

Comment: Tom, I've found the solution even before I've posted the question, but after I was ready to. So I decided to use the "Post your question and answer" button. Btw thanks for the link above..