# My rails time zone keeps changing dynamically every few seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something extremely weird is going on with my Rails application. In one of my models, I have the attribute `schedule` and it's configured as `datetime`. In my view, I have a table that goes through each Post and displays its schedule as `post.schedule`.

For example, I have one of the products set for 9:00 AM CST, as shown below:

```
2.5.0 :003 > Post.first.schedule.strftime("%l:%M %p")
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => " 9:00 AM"
```

Here's what it looks like in my view.

```
<td width="15%"><%= post.schedule.strftime("%a, %B %d, %Y") %> @ <%= post.schedule.strftime("%l:%M %p") %></td>
```

In the actual HTML page though, it keeps flipping between 3:00 AM to 9:00 AM. Literally, I can refresh the page twice in 30 seconds and it will flip between the two.

Any idea what could possibly be causing this? It's obviously flipping between UTC and CST, but I'm not sure how to stop this from happening and only use CST.

If the Post's schedule is not changing, why is the  time zone constantly flipping back and forth?

Comment: did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752810/rails-change-default-timezone

Comment: Do you run multiple server instances, e.g. with a load balancer?

Comment: @jdno Nope. Just this one rails app.

Comment: @HaseebEqx Yep I've made sure to include that in my config/application.rb and restarted the app. It looks like this may have updated it correctly in the database. Might be the solution here.

Comment: @LewlSauce are you saying it worked or not?

Comment: @HaseebEqx it appears that this fixed the issue. thanks a lot!